# Test Button click on RecyclerView

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

I want to test `performclick` on a button in `recyclerview` using [`Robolectric`](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) and I want to see that it opens the `activity` that I desire.This is what I did but this one does not let me click on a button.

```
ActivityController<MyActivity> activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(MyActivityclass);
activityController.create().start().visible();

ShadowActivity myActivityShadow = shadowOf(activityController.get()); 

RecyclerView currentRecyclerView = ((RecyclerView) myActivityShadow.findViewById(R.id.myrecyclerid));
currentRecyclerView.getChildAt(0).performClick();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember exactly but the specifics with `Robolectric` that it doesn't call view `onMeasure` `onLayout` or it calls it with **0dp** size.

However, this is a key to let know the `RecyclerView` that his `LayoutManager` should start inflating items to present them on the screen.

You could call `onMeasure` of the `RecyclerView` with some big numbers in your test and then it should trigger adding items to the screen.

However, I would leave this type of tests to the espresso one because it is a really high-level test.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already did with Espresso which works perfect, but I was wondering about the same thing for Robolectric. I am new to this testing technique. Thanks again.

Comment: Robolectric is nice, but hassle about to fix issues when a new version comes is quite high. As well it is still slow tests. So, you should decide but majority android devs are still using espresso now.